# Count number of times a link is clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So i'm trying to record the number of times a link is clicked but can't get over the last hurdle.

I have the following so far:

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :papers do 

    resources :articles do

        resources :clicks
    end 
end
```

**click.rb**

```
class Click < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :article, counter_cache: true

    validates :ip_address, uniqueness: {scope: :article_id}
end
```

**clicks_controller.rb**

class ClicksController < ApplicationController

```
def create

        @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])

        @click = @article.clicks.new(ip_address: request.ip)

        @click.save

    end
end
```

**article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base


  has_many :clicks

end
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "clicks", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.string   "ip_address"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "articles", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.text     "title"
    t.string   "url"
    t.integer  "paper_id"
    t.integer  "clicks_count"
  end
```

**index.html.erb -- articles**

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>

   <div class="articles col-md-4">

   <%= link_to article.url,  target: '_blank' do %>

   <h4><%= article.title %></h4>
   <h5><%= article.paper.name.upcase %></h5>
   <h6><%= article.created_at.strftime("%d %B %y") %></h6>
<% end %>
```

Firstly, does this setup look correct, does anyone see where i may have gone wrong?
Secondly, what i don't know how to set up my view so that when the existing link is clicked the click is registered and the count goes up?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with the following.

**clicks_controller.rb**

Original:

```
def create

        @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])

        @click = @article.clicks.new(ip_address: request.ip)

        @click.save

    end
end
```

Amended:

```
def create

        @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])

        @click = @article.clicks.new(ip_address: request.ip)

        @click.save

        redirect_to @article.url


    end
end
```

**index.html.erb -- articles**

Original:

```
<%= link_to article.url,  target: '_blank' do %>
```

Amended:

```
<%= link_to paper_article_views_path(article.id, article), method: :post,  target: '_blank' do %>
```

Also, i edited the original question to include the `routes.rb` file.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should do 2 things :

**1) Set all the methods for "clicks" into a Model**

For example, you can remove your `ClicksController` and add this :

```
class Article
  def create_click(ip_address)
    self.clicks.create({ :ip_address => ip_address })
  end
end
```

A little note with this code : you have a uniqueness validation in your code. Indeed, when a click already exists for an article and an ip address, the `create` method will return false. Do not use `create!` instead, or it will raise an exception.

**2) Add a filter :**

You can simply add a filter in your `ArticlesController`. At each `show`, it will create a `click` instance for the viewed `article`

```
class ArticlesController
  before_filter :create_click, :only => [ :show ]

  def create_click
     @article.create_click(ip_address)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @ForgetTheNorm, i've actually just got this working by replacing the original link_to with `<%= link_to paper_article_views_path(article.id, article), method: :post,  target: '_blank' do %>` but what i still do't get is why i needed to give the route `article.id` AND `article`?? i figured it out through trial and error..Thanks

Comment: @James Edit your original message and share your `config/routes`, your routes are weird.

Comment: I've added `routes.rb`. Are you saying that the way the routes are nested is the reason i had to give `article.id` and `article` to the route? cheers

Comment: OK I understand now. It's not `article.id`, but `paper` or `article.paper`. To understand, run a `rake routes` into your console. You will get a line like this : `paper_article  GET /papers/:paper_id/articles/:id`. It means that the `paper_article` route should have 2 parameters : a `paper` and a `article`.