# Count plays, jPlayer - Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jplayer

I'm starting with Rails.

I'm using jPlayer and i would like to know the number of reproductions of a song.

I have the model 'Song', with a field 'plays', but it do not belong(do not perform,am not) how to implement a function that helps me to counting(telling) the reproductions. I have looked for information, but I have not found her. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could count the times each link for each Song has been clicked creating a Model for clicks (or "plays", however you want to call it) and associating it to your Songs. Check this link for an idea:

[Count number of times a link is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647016/count-number-of-times-a-link-is-clicked)

It's of your interest to know how Associations work:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html